# Visual Studio Error list not updating while running a debug session

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, rhino3d

[image]

Hi all, I made a error on line 33. It is highlighted with the squiggly line.
Yet in the Error List it is giving me the error that was before I run the Debug.
Does Error List not work with Hot Reload?

Version: Visual Studio Community 2019

Comment: Single quotes are used to delimit a single character. For strings you should use double quotes. Pretty sure that if your clean and rebuild your error list window will show you the exact error message

Comment: Yes i intentionally made that error. Yet it is not showing in the Error List while i am debugging. I am doing HotReload for some of my scripts yet the Error List does not update whenever I change my code (and make an error) during the Debug session